# FactoryGirl - using traits not giving expecting result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

When I define my User factory this way

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
      roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:role, :system, :admin)]}
      email "visitor.administration@example.com"
      name  "Visitor Administration"
      password "visitor123"
    end
  end
```

with the following  Role factory :

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :role do
        company "internal"
        group "administration"
        function "visitor"
        activities '{}'
      end
      trait :system do
        group "system"
      end
      trait :admin do
        function "admin"
        activities '{"sheet" => ["create", "update", "delete", "show", "index"] }'
      end  
    end
```

executing

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

gives me the expected result ...

BUT if I try to define a trait in the User factory

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
      roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:role)]}
      email "visitor.administration@example.com"
      name  "Visitor Administration"
      password "visitor123"

      trait :system_admin do
        roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:role, :system, :admin)]}
        email "admin.system@example.com"
        name  "Admin System"
        password "admin123"
      end
      factory :system_admin_user,  traits: [:system_admin ] 
    end
  end
```

and I execute now :

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:system_admin_user)
```

Then I get an error :

```
    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (5.4ms)  INSERT INTO "roles" ("group", "function", "activities", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["group", "system"], ["function", "admin"], ["activities", nil], ["created_at", "2015-09-19 09:08:19.572605"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-19 09:08:19.572605"]]
    PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "activities" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, internal, system, admin, null, 2015-09-19 09:08:19.572605, 2015-09-19 09:08:19.572605).
```

Is the activities JSON field incorrectly defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the activities attribute is not written correctly :

```
activities '{"sheet" => ["create", "update", "delete", "show", "index"] }'
```

SHOULD BE :

activities {{ sheet: ["create", "update", "delete", "show", "index"] }}